Validate items in array using Vuelidate
I have a main document with several attached documents. The main document has a start and end date. The attached document has a type, status and date. Status 0 - the document is not needed, 1 - waiting for the document, 2 - the document is attached and has a date.
I want to check two options:

If the attached document has a status = 2, it should have a date
The date of the attached document should be in the range between the start and end dates in the main document.

I tried to use Collections validation from https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-validation-groups
$each: {name: {required}}

My code:
add_docs: {$each: {date: {required}}}  

Works, but requires date for all elements in add_docs
How I can use IF (status===2) then Required?
How can I get the Status value for the current item in $each?
All code
import { required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
  data() {
   return {
    doc: {
        number: 'A123',
        date_start: '2024-01-01',
        date_finish: '2024-02-01',
        add_docs: [
            {
            type: 'One',
            date: '',
            status: 0 // The document is not needed
            },
            {
            type: 'Two',
            date: '',
            status: 1 // Waiting for the document
            },
            type: 'Three',
            date: '2024-02-10', // This date out of range between date_start and date_finish
            status: 2 // The document is attached and has a date
            },
        ]
    }
  },
  validations: {
    doc {
        number: {required},
        date_start: {required},
        date_finish: {
            check_date: function (value) { // Check date_start > date_finish
                if (!value) {
                    return true;
                }
                return (new Date(value) >= new Date(this.doc.date_start));
            }
        },
        add_docs: {
            $each: {
                date: { required }  // Works, but requires date for all elements in add_docs
            }
        }
    }
  }
}



There's requiredIf, it can possibly solve this. Or you can use custom validator instead of builtin ones if you need some custom behaviour from it
